# try/catch failing incorrectly + console commands taking input but not running

Tags: java, html, exception

So I'm currently taking AP Comp Sci A and am trying to learn Java, and while developing a small program to keep up with my teacher I've run into a couple issues.

The program is intended to take entries and log them in a journal. I'd eventually like to have it stored in an HTML format and then be able to email my logs to a teacher in an HTML table, but this issue is preventing that.

Basically, with my catch, I'm trying to create and then enter starting HTML code (,, and then necessary tags for the html table) but even if the file doesn't exist the catch isn't running correctly, presumably because of the 'throws IOException' Exclipse had me add.

I also attempted to add commands to my program, but nothing happens when used. No exceptions thrown, nothing printed, etc.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LogSend {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Type '!help' for commands");

        Scanner cmd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String initialCmd = cmd.nextLine();


        if (initialCmd == "!help") {
            System.out.println("The commands are:");
            System.out.println("'!help' for commands");
            System.out.println("'!log' to log an entry");
        } else if (initialCmd == "!log") {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println(timeStamp);

            Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
            String journalEntry = entry.nextLine();
            try (PrintWriter saveLog = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.html", true))) {
                saveLog.println(timeStamp+":"+"<b>"+journalEntry+"</b>"+"<br>");

            }
        }


        /*String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(timeStamp);

        Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
        String journalEntry = entry.nextLine();
        try (PrintWriter saveLog = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.html", true))) {
            saveLog.println(timeStamp+":"+"<b>"+journalEntry+"</b>"+"<br>");

        } /*catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("log.html");
            PrintWriter saveLog = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            saveLog.println("<html>");
            saveLog.println("<body>");
            saveLog.println(timeStamp+":"+journalEntry);
            saveLog.println("</body>");
            saveLog.println("</html>");
        }*/



    }

}
```

Sorry if this is all a bit stupid, I'm brand new to Java and find I learn best through just making programs. I appreciate the help.

NOTE: It's worth noting I've commented out the catch because it's simply not working, but that's the code I used.

Comment: Why do you want to write to a file in the catch clause? The is meant to be used for exception/error handling, i.e. when something that you tried did not work is intended.

Comment: @AKSW as I kept getting an exception due to the file not existing, I used the catch to handle that exception, create a new file, and then write the base html to that file. When writing that though Eclipse told me to add the other exception handler as mentioned in the OP. What way would you recommend dealing with it (making the base html file) aside from using an exception?

Answer (score 0):

First String comparison goes by a method `equals`

```
initialCmd == "!help"
initialCmd.equals("!help") // Or equalsIgnoreCase
```

Then

```
        try (PrintWriter saveLog = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.html", true))) {
            saveLog.println(timeStamp+":"+"<b>"+journalEntry+"</b>"+"<br>");

        }
```

is okay, as it writes to the file in **append** mode (the `true`) and will almost never throw a FileNotFoundException (=could not create file).

You may do:

```
    try (...
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As FileNotFoundException is also an IOException. For out-of-diskspace, missing rights, wrong directory path.

One remark: FileWriter will use the default (=platform) encoding. For
the full Unicode range that a String is capable of, you could use UTF-8:

```
      try (PrintWriter saveLog = new PrintWriter(
              Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("log.html"),
                  StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                  StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
                  StandardOpenOption.CREATE))) {
          saveLog.printf("%s:<b>%s</b><br>%n", timeStamp, journalEntry);
      }
```

Also not that one cause for an exception might be two thread logging to the file.

It would not be wrong to invest time in the **java.util.logging** framework that can be customized to about the same functionality, and more.

---

The above does not throw a catch on a non-existing file, assuming the same content being written.

For HTML one would like to write a beginning. One can do that by including the log file in a real HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <ENTITY log SYSTEM "log.html">
]>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Logs</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> <!-- reload every 5s -->
  </head>
  <body>
&log;
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help! It works well for the most part, however, when the file doesn't exist the catch isn't being ran. Also, how would you recommend dealing with HTML tags? Is there any way for me to properly insert my new info between the tags created in the catch? Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/Gxxy2Bkc

Comment: For special treatment in a catch remove the CREATE option, but actually then one would need to repeat the logging - once. I have added another way, where the log file is regular and it is _included_ in an HTML file.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. The only issue is I'm hoping to have this emailed to my instructor in the HTML format. I guess tables might just not work.

Answer (score 0):

@index.php For clarification, passing true as the 2nd argument of `FileWriter` (as @JoopEggen suggests) causes the file to be created if it doesn't exist and to be opened for appending if it does exist. Therefore you won't hit the catch as you'll create a new file `logs.html` and append to it once created. Isn't that what you're trying to do anyway? So if the catch is just for creating the file when it doesn't exist, it is no longer required?

On the other hand, if you're trying to log the fact the file never existed you can use `java.io.File` and do something like:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);

//Note we do !f.isDirectory() as exists will return true for directories too
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // log that file didn't exist
    // create file and append custom error
}
```

Though with this method you need to be careful not to run into race conditions.

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it out but it created a new file every time, which from what I can tell results because of the first line. The reason I tried using a catch is to setup the initial HTML file and then log to the same file daily, and then later email the HTML body to my instructor (only reason I'm using HTML is to format it nicely). Should I be trying to force and catch an IO Exception if the file doesn't exist? Appreciate the help.